# Приведение базового класса к дочернему

Tags: c++

```
struct A
{
    void B();
}
struct B : A
{
    void A();
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  
    B* a = new A();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Я знаю, что так нельзя делать, но почему? Как оно устроено в памяти?

Comment: У дочернего класса могут быть дополнительные поля, которых нет в родительском. То есть объект дочернего класса будет занимать больше памяти. А выделено меньше.

Comment: @MaximTimakov А если будут совпадать? Или размер все равно будет отличаться?

Comment: Тут лучше привести аналогию из реального мира: есть штука, которую называют мебелью. Мебель можно разместить в комнате и не важно что это за мебель. Но конкретная мебель используется по разному. Но в данный момент у вас есть информация о том что вещь у вас в руках просто мебель. Ее можно просто поставить в комнате, а не сесть на нее как на стул или лечь как на кровать. Мебель - обобщение, базовый класс. У вас просто нет информации какие дополнительные свойства есть. Вдруг там настенный шкаф вместо стола?

Comment: Стул является мебелью, но мебель не всегда стул. Класс A - мебель. B - стул.

Comment: Можно поговорить о том, как будет валиться на вызове, например, виртуальной функции, но этот довод, судя по имеющемуся комментарию, разобьется о "а если нет виртуальных функций?". Да делайте, почему нет... Понимаете, аналогия — это вы рветесь перебегать через дорогу на красный свет светофора. Вам говорят, что можно попасть под машину, но вы начинаете выяснять — а если машин нет, то можно? Ну бегите, в конце концов в программировании, если что, это не так смертельно, как через дорогу...